# Can't get an ASP Button to enable itself from code-behind after disabling it client-side

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET, so this surely comes from lack of understanding from my part.

I've come across an ASP Button that has both `OnClientClick` and `OnClick` set:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContent" runat="Server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSendData" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Block">
        ...
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" 
                OnClientClick="if(!CanSave()){return false;}; DisableSaveButton();"
                OnClick="btnSave_Click" 
                Text="<%$ Resources: btnSave %>"
                CssClass="cmdFormButton"
                UseSubmitBehavior="false" 
                Width="220px" />
</asp:Content>
```

The `OnClientClick` calls a JS function that disables the button, to avoid the user from accidentally clicking it more than once:

```
function DisableSaveButton() {
    document.getElementById("<%=btnSave.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
}
```

Then the code-behind `OnClick` does the saving process... But if something fails, I want to enable the button back. So I did this:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (SaveData())
    {
        // Redirects to another page
    }
    else
    {
        btnSave.Enabled = true;  // This is "true" already
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. The client-side code is being executed correctly before the code-behind, and the button is disabled alright. But if I debug the code-behind, `btnSave.Enabled` returns `true` already, and it does not re-enable it.

I know the ASP `Enabled` property and the HTML `disabled` attribute are not the same, but I kinda expected ASP to know how to handle this.

Also, I'm not sure if (or how) I can access the `disabled` attribute from code-behind, anyway.

Any ideas? Suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you confirm the current behaviour. The button is being disabled on submit but not re-enabled when `SavaData() == false`?

Comment: Is this a full post back or is there an `UpdatePanel` or something similar involved? Is some other method in the code behind touching the button?

Comment: @user1429080 There's an `UpdatePanel`, indeed. There are some code-behind methods that mess with the button's `Visible` property, but none with the `Enabled` one.

Comment: I'll edit to add some more context to the asp code

Comment: @user1429080 Mmmh, looks like the button is not inside the `UpdatePanel`, so not sure if it affects this anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally managed to solve this. It was as "easy" as registering a script that called the JS function to enable the buttons client-side, from code behind.

CS:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (SaveData())
    {
        // Redirects to another page
    }
    else
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(),
            "showSaveButtons_" + this.ClientID, "EnableSaveButton();", true);
    }
}
```

ASPX:

```
function EnableSaveButton() {
    document.getElementById("<%=btnSave.ClientID %>").disabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the attributes...

```
 else
    {
        btnSave.Enabled = true;  // This is "true" already
        btnSave.Attributes.Remove("disabled");
    }
```

Also, you need to apply `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` to the button for the ``*code behind* to be called

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" UseSubmitBehavior="false"  
            runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnSave_Click" 
            OnClientClick="DisableSaveButton();" />
```

It's been a few years since I have used WebForms, so this is an *educated guess*.

Comment: Checked the `UseSubmitBehavior`, it's already `false`. Tried removing the attribute, but it's not there to begin with. `btnSave.Attributes` returns an empty collection. I'll add the aspx code of the button to the question.

Comment: What is `!CanSave()`?

Comment: It's a JS function that checks if the data is valid, to avoid sending a save request to the server if we know it won't work.

If `CanSave` returns `false`, it works as intended: the button stays enabled and the code-behind save code isn't called.

Comment: I have tested this on a dummy project, and it works fine - are you sure it's hitting the else block of code?

Comment: Yup, it is... I guess the code-behind "version" of the control is not aware of the changes made client-side by the JS script, which makes sense, but then the code-behind change doesn't seem to be noticed either.

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to be able to control a button disabled state from code-behind in an update panel. I used a function to inject a client-side onclick handler attribute that would set the disabled attribute to prevent multiple clicks and changed the `value` property to "Saving". Then in my OnClick code, if I set `Enabled=false` and forced my UpdatePanel to update, `upSendData.Update()`, this would force the panel to redraw all controls in their current state. btn1 was drawn enabled, and btn2 disabled. The value (text) was also reset automatically.

**ASPX Page**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSendData" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
....
    <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Email Instructions" OnClick="btn1_Click" Enabled="false" />        
    <asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btn2_Click" />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

ASPX.CS

```
public void disableSubmitButtonOnClick(Button objButton, String message = "Processing") {
        objButton.CausesValidation = false;
        string validationGroup = objButton.ValidationGroup;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(validationGroup))
            objButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", String.Format("if (Page_ClientValidate()) {{this.value='{0}...';this.disabled=true;{1} }}", message, objButton.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(objButton, "").ToString()));
        else
            objButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", String.Format("if (Page_ClientValidate(\"{2}\")) {{this.value='{0}...';this.disabled=true; {1} }}", message, objButton.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(objButton, "").ToString(), validationGroup));
}
Page_Load()
{
    if(!IsPostBack())
    {
        disableSubmitButtonOnClick(btn1);
        disableSubmitButtonOnClick(btn2);
    }
}

protected void btn2_Click()
{
btn2.Enabled = false;
btn1.Enabled = true;
upSendData.Update(); 
}
```

If the button is outside the UpdatePanel, then you need to RegisterClientScript to reset the button state (assumes jQuery):

```
public void resetSubmitButton(Button objButton, Boolean state=true)
{
    String sState = (!state).ToString().ToLower();
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "reset" + objButton.ID, String.Format("$('#{0}').val('{1}');$('#{0}').attr('disabled', {2});", objButton.ClientID, objButton.Text, sState), true);
}

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    resetSubmitButton((Button)sender);
}
```